# How to trigger click event on command button in JSF, after the evalution of action EL expression

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried all available solutions from net but the command button is not been auto clicked.
I am Opening a JSF application from another application on the Link I am passing session id and getting the value stored in redis server against the session id. Everything is working except the auto click of login button
The below is UI code is of the Login page which I want to auto redirect to pages in the login () method of UserManagerNew Bean.
Please help me solve the issue.

```
    <html>   
    <body>
    <div id="login-overlay" class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">

              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Welcome To Adhoc 
                       Reports</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

                      <h:graphicImage library="images" name="kccaImg_1581071635760.jpg"/> 
                          <o:form id="login-form" class="form-horizontal" includeRequestParams="true" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                                
                              <h:commandButton id="submitLogin" value="Login" action="#{userManagerNew.login}" class="btn btn-success col-sm-7"></h:commandButton>  

                          </o:form>

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

      <script>

       window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('submitLogin').click();
       } 

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

My Managed Bean is as Below.

```
  @ManagedBean(name = "userManagerNew", eager = true)
       @RequestScoped
       @Service
       public class UserManagerNew {

    private String user;

    private String password;

    private Integer ulbId;

    private String key;

    String ulbName;

    private List<Ulb> ulbs = new ArrayList<>();

    String errorTitle;

    String errorDetails;

    Boolean logine = false;

    Manager manager;

    private String sessionData;

    @Autowired
    private GisRedisRepository redisRepository;


    @PostConstruct
    private void init() throws SQLException {

        manager = SpringUtil.getService(Manager.class);
        ulbs = manager.getAllULBs();
        Map<String, Object> mp = getUserDetails();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getUserDetails(){
        Integer ADMINULB=9999;
        Integer STATEULB=999;
        String ADMINCODE="ADMIN";
        String STATECODE="KCCA";

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) (facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest());
        if(request.getParameter("key")!=null && !request.getParameter("key").isEmpty()) {
            key = request.getParameter("key");
        }

        String usrDtlsJson =redisRepository.validateLoggedInUser(key);
        UserBean loggedUsr = (UserBean) new Gson().fromJson(usrDtlsJson, UserBean.class);
        ulbId = loggedUsr.getUlbId().equals(STATEULB)?ADMINULB:STATEULB;
        Map<String, Object> mp = new HashMap<>();
        mp.put("USERBEAN", loggedUsr);
        return mp;
    }

    public String login() throws SQLException {

        Integer ADMINULB=9999;
        Integer STATEULB=999;
        String ADMINCODE="ADMIN";
        String STATECODE="KCCA";

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) 
      facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        UserBean loggedUsr=null;



        Map<String, Object> mp = getUserDetails();
        UserBean usrBean = (UserBean)mp.get("USERBEAN");
        ulbId = usrBean.getUlbId().equals(STATEULB)?ADMINULB:STATEULB;
        logine = true;




        if(getUlbId() == null || getUlbId() == 0) {
            setErrorTitle("ULB Not selected");
            setErrorDetails("Please select ULB");
            logine = false;
            return "Error.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }


            String ulbname = manager.getUlbName(getUlbId());
                if(ulbname.equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")) {
                    logine = true;
                    return "allUlbs.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
                }

                logine = true;
        return "ReportsNew.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getErrorTitle() {
        return errorTitle;
    }

    public void setErrorTitle(String errorTitle) {
        this.errorTitle = errorTitle;
    }

    public String getErrorDetails() {
        return errorDetails;
    }

    public void setErrorDetails(String errorDetails) {
        this.errorDetails = errorDetails;
    }

    public Boolean getLogine() {
        return logine;
    }

    public void setLogine(Boolean logine) {
        this.logine = logine;
    }

    public Integer getUlbId() {
        return ulbId;
    }

    public void setUlbId(Integer ulbId) {
        this.ulbId = ulbId;
    }

    public List<Ulb> getUlbs() {
        return ulbs;
    }

    public void setUlbs(List<Ulb> ulbs) {
        this.ulbs = ulbs;
    }



    public String getUlbName() {
        return ulbName;
    }

    public void setUlbName(String ulbName) {
        this.ulbName = ulbName;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }   

  }
```

Comment: Check your JS console and debugger. The `document.getElementById('submitLogin')` returns undefined.

Comment: But if I click on login button removing the script code it functions well.. please tell me where I need to correct or provide me the link with reference of which my problem will be solved. Thanks in advance

Comment: The duplicate is linked in top of your question.

Comment: I apologise I didn't noticed it. Thanks for referring again.